# How can I regex this array/string?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
array = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']
output = array.toString()
```

This gets me `"item1,item2,item3,item4"` but I need to turn this into `"item1, item2, item3, and item4"` with spaces and "and"

How could I construct a regex process to do this rather then substringing and find/replacing?

Is this the best way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version handles all the variations I could think of :

```
function makeList (a) {
  if (a.length < 2)
    return a[0] || '';

  if (a.length === 2)
    return a[0] + ' and ' + a[1];

  return a.slice (0, -1).join (', ') + ', and '  + a.slice (-1);
}    

console.log ([makeList ([]), 
              makeList (['One']), 
              makeList (['One', 'Two']), 
              makeList(['One', 'Two', 'Three']),
              makeList(['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'])]);

// Displays : ["", "One", "One and Two", "One, Two, and Three", "One, Two, Three, and Four"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var array = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'];
array.push('and ' + array.pop());
var output = array.join(', ');
// output = 'item1, item2, item3, and item4'
```

---

Edit: if you really do want a regex-based solution:

```
var output = array.join(',')
    .replace(/([^,]+),/g, '$1, ').replace(/, ([^,]+)$/, ' and $1');
```

---

Another edit:

Here's another non-regex approach that doesn't mess with the original `array` variable:

```
var output = array.slice(0,-1).concat('and ' + array.slice(-1)).join(', ');
```

Comment: But it does change the array which might cause problems downstream. Also does not quite work for arrays of length 1.

Comment: I guess if that's a problem you can just do `array2 = array.slice()`;

Comment: Good point though - I should have mentioned that my approach isn't side-effect free.

Comment: Added two alternative approaches - one with regular expressions, and another one that does array manip, but leaves `array` intact.

Answer (score 0):

```
var output = array.join(", ");
output = outsput.substr(0, output.lastIndexOf(", ") + " and " + output.substr(output.lastIndexOf(" and "));
```